# Joomla user profile plug-in not working

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have a Joomla 1.7 site.  I've enabled the User profile plug-in.  This allows extra fields to be added during registration (i.e. Address, Phone, etc.).

The only thing I want out of this is the "Terms of Service".  I want to make this a "Required" option so everyone has to agree to the terms of service.  In the admin interface I can set that up and it shows nicely as a mandatory option for the user.

However it doesn't work.  You can still register without having to click the terms of service radio button.  I'm not sure where to go from here.  Seems like a bug.  Joomla forum posts haven't yielded anything either.

Anyone know what I can use as a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, popular problem!  This patch may help: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=26643

Comment: Thanks, I did find this but it still didn't help.  My problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

To validate whether the user has completed the field or not, use a plugin such as http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/7361

You will need to add the TOS via the plugin for validation to work. The plugin will prevent the form from being posted before all the required fields are completed.